# Rails Custom route, how to remove ?id=

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, custom-routes

My app has a model msa with a `:name` and `:short_name`.

On the msa index page, there is a drop-down menu of all msa.names so the user can route to the show page of the selected msa.

This functionality is coded with a collection_select that routes to a custom method in the msa controller.

msa index view:

```
<%= form_with url: 'msas/redirect', method: :post, local: true do |f| %>
<%= f.collection_select(:id, Msa.all, :id, :name)%>
  <%= f.submit "Search" %>
<% end %>
```

msa controller redirect method:

```
 def redirect
    @msa=Msa.find(params[:id])
    redirect_to msa_path(@msa, short_name: @msa.short_name, id: @msa.id)
  end
```

Rather than have routes that read localhost:3000/msa/1, I want them to read localhost:3000/search/:short_name.

My routes.rb:

```
  scope format: false do
    resources :msas, :only => [:show], path: '/search', param: :short_name
  end
  resources :msas, :except => [:show]
```

Everything seems to work ok, except the route appears like this in the browser:

localhost:3000/search/Chicago?id=1

I tried remove the id: @msa.id from the redirect method, but ended up with this error:

```
Couldn't find Msa without an ID
```

which was keyed off the `set_msa` method in the msa controller.

I'm wondering two things:  a) have I strayed too far from typical rails convention, and b) if there is a way to do this and not reveal the id# of my msa models to the world?

Comment: use https://github.com/norman/friendly_id this gem and create slug on short_name. it will make sure that the generated slugs are unique to avoid any conflict

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If there is a way to do this and not reveal the id# of my msa models
>   to the world?

Just remove the `id` from the *path helper*

```
redirect_to msa_path(@msa, short_name: @msa.short_name)
```

and counter the error by defining a new method and removing the entry for `show` method in the `set_msa` like so

```
before_action :set_custom_msa, only: [:show]
before_action :set_msa, only: [:edit, :update,..] #remove the entry for show

private
def set_custom_msa
  @msa = Msa.find_by(short_name: params[:short_name])
end
```

> Have I strayed too far from typical rails convention

No! but if your final goal is to hide `:id` from the *URL* and to make *user-friendly URLs*, then I would suggest you to look at [**friendly_id**](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id)

Comment: Works perfectly!  Thanks